# Extract a table from a MySQL database using mysql/databasename folder

Tags: mysql

I am not an SQL expert, not even a novice so please excuse me if this question is naive. I have a copy of an old Linode drive where my Joomla website was hosted. I think that the Joomla database is located in "/var/lib/mysql/sitename".

I need to extract a specific table from this database but the database is not online anymore and I can not boot up from that drive anymore. What is the procedure to extract the info that I need from that database? (I know the table name from the Joomla documentation).

Comment: Is it MyISAM or InnoDB? Do you have access to the whole MySQL data directory or only the specific table? Can you copy the data somewhere and start a MySQL instance over it? That would be the easiest solution.

Comment: I do not know the answer to your first question. How do I find out what type it is? I can access the entire disk (mounted in Ubuntu). Yes I can copy the data anywhere I want. How do I copy and start MySql over it? By simply installing mysql and copying the folder to the same folder name on the new computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see [tablename].MYD and [tablename].MYI files it's MYISAM. If you see [tablename].ibd or only the .frm file then it's InnoDB. Based on that the process:

MyISAM

You can simply copy the .MYI, .MYD and .frm files to any existing MySQL instance's database directory.

For example:

You have your database in `/var/lib/mysql/sitename` then you find the table which will be `/var/lib/mysql/sitename/[dbname]/[tablename].*` (.MYD, .MYI and .frm). You can copy only these three files to an arbitrary database on a newly installed MySQL like `/var/lib/mysql/sitename/[restored_db]/`.

InnoDB

It's possible to import tablespace since 5.6 but if you can it's much simpler to copy the whole directoy. It's a common procedure to clone new replication slaves.

In your case you copy the whole `/var/lib/mysql/sitename` directory onto the new server and start MySQL over it. Make sure the innodb_log_file_size and innodb_log_files_in_group matches the size and number of what you have now. These are the files called `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`.

---

When you have the server running you can use mysqldump or any other method you prefer.

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks a lot. I did not have to change ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 :-) I was too lazy and I risked and I simply copied the folder and that was it, I restarted SQL and that was the end of it :-) Thanks again